# Inherit shared razor view in partial razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a shared view, which I want to inherit in partial view. It gives me an error

> System.InvalidOperationException
>   The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.**

My Shared View Like this :

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

My Partial View Like this :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

AND My Controller action Like following :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{           
    return PartialView();     
}
```

Comment: Have you created a view named `Index.cshtml` for that controller?

Comment: Yes, when I right click on controller and select "Go To View" it takes me to the partial view index.cshtml.

Comment: What is your shared view  ? Do you mean the Layout ?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC, setting `Layout` property in Partial Views is not a good practice, because the Layout modifies the content of the parent View as well. I didn't understand your objective, but I believe that you want to repeat some HTML elements in the referred Partial.

The recommended solution, if you want to repeat these elements in a Partial View, is to render a Partial View inside another Partial View using `@Html.Partial("_PartialInsidePartial")`.